# For loop to last value in matrix

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, matrix

I am looping down each row in an array, and the array variable size is 76 or so columns and 1000 rows. But, the matrix is not full, and the rows do not fill all 1,000. However, I need to keep my matrix this size, as it may grow in the future. What is the syntax for going until you hit the last element in an array? This is what I am currently stuck with. Thanks

```
Do While i <= 1000
```

Comment: range("a1000").end(xlUp).row

Comment: @Nathan_Sav He asked about "going to the last element in an array" and that would be `UBound(array)`. U = Upper and L = Lower. So, you can use `For i = LBound(array) to UBound(array)`.

Comment: You can have a dynamic array, that will grow as the number of rows fills. Use the `ReDim` command to dynamic define your array

Comment: @Ralph & Justin, Apologies, the word Row, threw me, yes, sorry use the Bound functions for an array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop until your array value isEmpty().

```
Option Base 0
Dim i As Long
Dim myArray(75, 999)

Do While Not IsEmpty(myArray(i, 0))
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

or

```
Option Base 1
Dim i As Long
Dim myArray(76, 1000)
i = 1
Do While Not IsEmpty(myArray(i, 0))
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Shai Rado is correct you should use a dynamic array.  [Excel VBA Array Tutorial](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=133:excel-vba-arrays-one-dimensional-a-multi-dimensional-dynamic-arrays-redim-statement-lower-a-upper-bound-200-year-calendar-excel-vba-paramarray&Itemid=473)